# javascript open modal window return values,, i dont get it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, showmodaldialog

I am not getting this Modal window / javascript stuff , I’m a bit of a noob I ve found tons of stuff about this trawling around
But its hard to find the answer when you lack the experience to ask the correct question.
and are not up to speed with all the jargon either

System.windows.froms.messagebox   doesn’t work in a web situation.. I’ve discovered that much,,,  This is an intranet application

How do I evaluate the result of the javascript function OpenDialogue() in a similar way to declaring DialogResult myVar =

I have a button event handler like this

```
protected void but_Comds(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = results.SelectedRow;
            string crn = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[13].Text);

            if (sender == but_crn)
            {
                checkData(row, crn);
            }
        }
```

Then some methods

```
        private void checkData(GridViewRow row, string crn)
        {
            if (stuff)
            {
                DialogResult checkCrn = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("a mesage",
                "Data Check",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel); 


                if (checkCrn == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    Do stuff;
                }
                if (checkCrn == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Do other stuff;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Do stuff instead
            }
        }
```

I can get the dialogue to run easy enough as a child page but I can’t work out capture the return value from the child page.
I have been trying to wrap it into a method amongst other things
And I can see this doesn’t work because ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript  Is void.

```
protected string MsgDialogue()
    {

       Return ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                    "newWindow", String.Format("<script>OpenDialog();</script>"));


    }
```

I have also tried okClicked(object sender, eventargs e) methods in the childs code behind
And tried to write a variable into the MySession class and  then get that variable in the checkData (row, crn) method
There must be some simple more elegant way of doing this without having to trawl thousands of pages
Hoping to stumble on it..

Here is my javascript on the mainpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog() {
        // get the control values
        var str1 = 'test';
        // create an array with the values
        var winArgs = new Array(str1);
        var winSettings = 'center:yes;resizable:no;help:no;status:no;dialogWidth:250px;dialogHeight:200px';

        // return the dialog control values after passing them as a parameter
        winArgs = window.showModalDialog('child.aspx', winArgs, winSettings);

        // see if the array is null
        if (winArgs == null) {
            window.alert('no data returned!');
        }
        return winArgs;

    }   
</script>
```

Here is child.aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <base target="_self"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            // intialize variables and array to empty
           var str1 = '';
           var winArgs = new Array(str1);

            // get the values as arguments and set the controls
            winArgs = window.dialogArguments;
            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = winArgs[0];            
        }

        function but_ok() {
            window.returnValue = "ok";
            window.close();
        }
        function but_cancel() {
            window.returnValue = "cancel";
            window.close();
        }
        function but_yes() {
            window.returnValue = "yes";
            window.close();
        }
        function but_no() {
            window.returnValue = "no";
            window.close();
        }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="GetData()">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly ="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="dlg_ok" runat="server" Text=" OK " /> 
    <asp:Button ID="dlg_cancel" runat="server" Text=" Cancel " /> 
    <asp:Button ID="dlg_yes" runat="server" Text=" Yes " />
    <asp:Button ID="dlg_no" runat="server" Text=" No " /> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And child.aspx. cs

```
public class child : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox1;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button dlg_ok;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button dlg_cancel;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button dlg_yes;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button dlg_no;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                dlg_ok.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:but_ok()";
                dlg_cancel.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:but_cancel()";
                dlg_yes.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:but_yes()";
                dlg_no.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:but_no()";




            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry ive posted quite a bit of code but hopefully if you can see what I’m trying to do 
Then you might be able to better explain what I’m not getting.

Comment: At what step does it not do what you expect, and what are you expecting to occur at that step?

Comment: i cant work out how to get the return value from the function OpenDialogue()  the function returns   'return winArgs;' how do i get the value of WinArgs into my checkdata method....   so I can say string s = "the value of winArgs"...  If (s = "OK") { do stuff}

Comment: Looking at your `checkData` method, it's clear you're thinking of this application in a very `WinForm` kind of way, as though it's a client application. It's not. This is a web application, it has client-side, and server-side operation. Traditionally, data is sent from client-side to server-side with a `GET` (navigation), or `POST` (postback or callback), and data is sent from server-side to client-side in response to one of the above. If you're doing anything other than basic `WebForm`, you need to start thinking in terms of these `GET` and `POST` operations.

Comment: Thanks I sort of see what your saying and your correct in so far as I am not clear on what exactly happens on each side, or how they communicate with each other, although i am aware that both sides are there. I think that the javascript is at the client end running in the browser as it were (maybe) and the asp mark up is running in the browser too but the C# code behind is being run on the server....

Comment: SO   what i need to do is  'POST' the return value of the function  ...somewhere, to where ?? to the server side somewhere??  would i then be able to aceess it with my C# method... and where do i post it from??  i mean could i post it from the child page? or would i post it with the javascript.. forgive me for being dumb, could you perhaps link me to a relevant example.. Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Javascript is client-side. ASPX markup is first *processed* server-side, then transmitted to the client as HTML. Code-behind is server-side.

Comment: Keep in mind too that this is a request / response pattern, so your plan of having a client-side dialog part way through a server-side method isn't really going to work. If the client *requests* that `checkData` runs, and the server *responds* with "show a dialog", that's the end of server-side execution. The clients selection in the dialog needs to go back to the server as a new request. You're already `POST`ing data back to the server when `but_Comds` is executed, you could do something similar for a button in a dialog.